# Divs and layers

Tags: css, html

First here is the site: [www.rfdesignstudio.com/weavepublic/](http://www.rfdesignstudio.com/weavepublic/)

Second the CSS code:

```
#hoverbox {
    position:absolute;
    width:725px;
    height:132px;
    z-index:1;
    margin-left:-360px;
    left:50%;
    top: 740px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

the black box right after the tree section. i want it to stay right in that position, but when i use the panel up top it slides up cause the position is absolute.  i'm still learning css and want to have it stay in that spot.

Comment: That is CSS and not HTML.

Comment: lol um i provided the link so people could see the source, was i supposed to paste it here?

Comment: Yes lol indeed, I reacted to the `Second the html code` part though, which you just edited ;)

Comment: It's generally looked down upon to post any outside links unless it's from jsFiddle, which is recommended.  Whether you post a jsFiddle or not, try to post the most simple example of the problem directly in your question.

Comment: Somebody edited to change "Here's my CSS" to "Second the HTML code". @RafaelFernandezJr. -- you should paste your source here because if your source changes or your URL changes, then your question will not be relevent to future users. Furthermore, it's usually helpful to create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: oh i didnt edit the html yet. im still having the problem :-( when people use the panel button up top, and it slides down the box doestn move with the site, it stay in the spot, and covers the tree section.

Comment: ah im new i dont have any clue about jsfiddle :-( just though id post the question to see if there was a SOLUTION :-)

Comment: I would specify which browser you're using, working fine in my chrome

Comment: On all three browsers the black box stats static, doesn't move down with the content.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right in understanding, you would like the green box to appear on top of the rest of the content? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

For this you would need to to change the css of the panel to this.

```
#panel {
background: #749311;
height: 200px;
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: -200px;
}
```

and then when you click the `.btn-slide` you would animate the top position to 0px. Something like this.

```
$('.btn-slide').live('click',function () {
    $('#panel').animate({top:0});
});
```

---

**EDIT**
Now I understand. Please see below.

If you change `#wrapper {over:visible;}`

And

```
#hoverbox {
position: relative;
width: 725px;
height: 132px;
z-index: 1;
visibility: visible;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

I think this should work

Comment: i think i confused my question.  The panel up top i dont have an issue with, its supposed to slide down.   what im trying to accomplish is that the #hoverbox move down with the content, but the absolute position is making it use the top and i cant figure how to attach it to the section its in at that place.

Comment: Please see the edit below my original answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: wow so close, is there a way for me to move it up a couple of pixels?

Comment: Yes relative positioning still understands the top style attribute so you should be able to add 'top:-2px'

Comment: PS dont forget to tick the answer if it's solved the issue =)

Comment: oh i was doing it differently , let me try that

Comment: There's a little tick underneath the vote up and down next to my answer. Glad I could help.